# What is the use of this line-" if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString())) { vid = ((int)dt.Rows[0][0] + 1)"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm setting up a web application's Vendor login page. In this i used this code, but i am not sure of it's working. So can anyone explain this code line by line.

```
private void GetVendorID()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "Select Max(VID) from Vendor";
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int row = sd.Fill(dt);
            string vid = "101";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString())) 
            { 
                  vid = ((int)dt.Rows[0][0] + 1).ToString(); 
            }
            lbId.Text = vid;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I expected the Vendor ID to be fetched into the TextBox directly when the Vendor is directed to the Login Page after Registering himself. In short,the Vendor at first attempt to Login after Registering,will have the Login Id displayed in the TextBox with property Editable=False. But the actual output is the Vendor has to write the Login ID by himself at the first attempt to login.

Comment: the mentioned two lines of code checks if the data returned is null/empty, and if not, increments the value and stores in vid. Regarding why this might not be working, you might be interested to debug this and check if you are actually getting a valid value in the 'lbId.Text = vid'

Comment: I assume you inserted data when registering the vendor. Was this a stored procedure that was used because it should have an Out parameter returning he new PK. if you wrote your own Insert command you need to add a Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() . (not as good an option) You cannot come along later and expect Max(vid) to return a correct vid in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Something is terribly wrong if you don't know what your own code does. In addition, "not working" is a comment that no one but you can understand. You need to start thinking about your code and the proper use of datatypes. Why do you cast your column to int, then cast it to string, and then finally store it as a string in a local variable? If the ID column is a number, then you should refer to it, manipulate it, and store it as a number. Yes, your GUI control displays a string but that is the only place where it is needed. And you should reconsider displaying an assigned numeric ID to a user

Answer (score 0):

If there is data in vendor table then we are incrementing that id using

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString())) 
{ 
    vid = ((int)dt.Rows[0][0] + 1).ToString(); 
}
```

or else it will by default

```
string vid = "101";
```